# PDF, when printed, comes out with completely uneven inter-character spacing - when displayed on screen it is fine - how to fix?

Tags: pdf, printing, troubleshooting

Every once in awhile I download a pdf that looks fine on screen but when printed the inter-character spacing is all messed up.  See image below.

By fine on screen I mean in any browser's embedded pdf viewer, or in Adobe Reader, or in Foxit Reader.

And for printing I use Adobe Reader or Foxit Reader (this particular example was Foxit Reader but I'm nearly 98% sure I've seen it with Adobe Reader too.)

My current printer is a Lexmark C2425 with proper Windows 10 drivers installed.  (Though it has happened with other printers, e.g., Brother, and Pixma, too.)

So, what's up and how do I troubleshoot it and fix it?  I suspect a font issue of some kind - though the pdfs this happens to are all academic papers which are nearly always produced by some LaTeX system using standard templates so I'm not *confident* it's a font issue.

(To be clear:  99.9% of all PDFs downloaded from whatever source look fine on the screen and *print absolutely A-OK*.  (But of course the one out of a thousand that is broken is the one I *really* want to read...)

[image]

(Please ignore the fact that I took a lousy photo with shadows of my fingers ... thank you ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for Foxit Reader but for Adobe Reader I've been able to work around such quirks by selecting `Print as image` in the Advanced print setup.
[image]

(Screenshot is from Acrobat Pro but the same option exists in Acrobat Reader.)

Comment: This worked with Foxit Reader.  Thanks!